# How to view the doc file which is stored in the root folder in razor pages

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I need to view the uploaded doc file contents when clicking on the 'VIEW' button,
My current code is downloading the file, instead of viewing the contents.
Here is my code

Attachment.cshtml

```
@if (Model.AttachForms != null)
            {
                <table class="table" border="1" style="width:500px;margin-left:300px;">
                    <thead style="background-color:#DC3545">
                        <tr>
                            <th>File</th>
                            <th width="100px"></th>
                            <th width="100px"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.AttachForms)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @*asp page handler with define on post method*@
                                    <form asp-page-handler="view" method="post">
                                        <input asp-for="EmpID" type="hidden" value='@Request.Query["EmpID"]' />
                                        <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="@item.Name" />
                                        <button class="btn btn-success">View</button>
                                    </form>
                                    @*<img src="~/images/pencil(1).png" alt="Edit">
                                    <a asp-page-handler="view" asp-route-id="@item.Name">Edit</a>*@
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <form asp-page-handler="delete" method="post">
                                        <input asp-for="EmpID" type="hidden" value='@Request.Query["EmpID"]' />
                                        <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="@item.Name" />
                                        <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                                        @*<img src="~/images/icons8-delete-trash-16.png" alt="Delete">
        <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Name">Delete</a>*@
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            }
            @if (Model.AttachForms == null)
            {
                <div class="text-center">
                    <p>No Files To Display</p>
                </div>
            }
```

Attachment.cshtml.cs

```
public IActionResult OnPostView()
        {
            string filename = Request.Form["filename"];
            if (filename != null)
            {
                var Folder = EmpID.ToString();
                string fileview = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "Documents/EmployeeAttachments", Folder, filename);
                WebClient User = new WebClient();
                Byte[] fileBuffer = User.DownloadData(fileview);
                if (fileBuffer != null)
                {
                    return new FileContentResult(fileBuffer, "application/ms-word");
                }
            }
            return Page();
        }
```

when I click on the view button, it is downloading the file, I want to view the file in the browser.

if I'm changing this code snippet

```
return new FileContentResult(fileBuffer, "application/ms-word");
```

to

```
return new FileContentResult(fileBuffer, "application/pdf");
```

it will be showing like this
[image]

Comment: Hi @Teena, I would recommend first convert the word to pdf with some tools, then store the pdf file in `wwwroot` folder instead. Chrome seems can't convert it automatically.

Comment: This [article](https://medium.com/@usman.aziz/document-viewer-in-asp-net-core-mvc-ed42353070a7) shows how to create a document viewer in ASP.NET Core MVC application by using **GroupDocs.Viewer**, but it's not free.

Answer (score 0):

Can be use Google document viewver in `HTML` `<iframe>` tag

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://remote.url.tld/path/to/document.doc&embedded=true"></iframe>
```